How to fix same side corners?
How do fix this? All other sides are fixed




Remove orange-green edge
Swap white and yellow corners
Set removed edge back


Is this a serious answer? It wouldn't be possible on all cubes, at least without irreversible damage.

@booble, well this speedcube maybe requires some screws to be spinned out.  Just two corner pieces cannot be swept without also swapping (at least) two edge pieces using legal moves only.

This cube is unsolvable without popping out the pieces, and putting it back together yourself.
Link: Answer to why it isn't possible.
